# Beginner: Two input lines repeating after each other

Tags: java

So for this code below, I need to create input lines for team names and weight. However,

Enter the name of member 2:

**and**

Enter the weight of member 2 in lbs (must be decimal value):

both print simultaneously. Any solution to this? I tried println, that doesn't help.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("The name of the team is: ");
        String teamName = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.print("Enter the name of member 1: ");
        String member1 = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.print("Enter the weight of member 1 in lbs (must be decimal value): ");
        double member1weight = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the name of member 2: ");
        String member2 = input.nextLine();
        
    System.out.print("Enter the weight of member 2 in lbs (must be decimal value): ");
        double member2weight = input.nextDouble();
            
    System.out.print("Enter the name of member 3: ");
        String member3 = input.nextLine();
            
    System.out.print("Enter the weight of member 3 in lbs (must be decimal value): ");
        double member3weight = input.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `input.nextLine();` after each double you read , like that :

```
System.out.print("The name of the team is: ");
        String teamName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the name of member 1: ");
        String member1 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the weight of member 1 in lbs (must be decimal value): ");
        double member1weight = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the name of member 2: ");
        String member2 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the weight of member 2 in lbs (must be decimal value): ");
        double member2weight = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the name of member 3: ");
        String member3 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the weight of member 3 in lbs (must be decimal value): ");
        double member3weight = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine();
```